# How to skip a state in a state machine using AASM

Tags: ruby, aasm

I'm using the ruby AASM gem.

Does anyone know what the right way to skip a state is?

```
class Job
  # ...

  event :stage1_completed do
    if stage2_completed?
      transitions from: :stage1, :to => :stage3
    else
      transitions from: :stage1, :to => :stage2
    end
  end

  # ...
end
```

What is the best way to set this up in AASM?

I am using this code in a set of resque jobs, thus stage1 is a resque job, which then updates the state and starts the next resque job be done.  Same for stage2, then stage3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `guards`.

```
event :stage1_completed do
    transitions from: :stage1, :to => :stage3, :guard => :stage2_completed? 
end
```

Comment: how would this handle the regular transition from :stage1 to :stage2?

Comment: Ah, I did not know that they would work in sequence and finish once the state was changed. Cool!